# CSS show span on top of everything

Tags: html, css

I need a tooltip to display on top of its parents. I tried setting the z-index and overflow values, but couldn't get the desired result.
The tooltip appears when hovering over the red box. Desired outcome: tooltip field appears on top so the left (and bottom) side is not under the parent AND the children can't go out of bounds (the scroll function needs to stay intact.

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 380px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 380px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.child-container {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-color: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 80%;
/*    width: calc((100% - 83px) / 3);*/
    margin: 20px 10px 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}

.header {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: 1pt solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

label {
    color: #757575;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: block;
}

.info {
    border: 0;
    height: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}

.info:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
}

.img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background: red;
}

.tooltip {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: #00c853;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: none;
    top: 150%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}

.tooltip.top:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #00c853;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #00c853;
    top: -20px;
    bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-container" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="header">MY HEADER</div>

        <div style="width:100%;margin:10px 10px 10px 0;text-align:left;">
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 1</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 2</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 3</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 4</span>
                <span class="info">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <span class="tooltip top" style="margin-left:-155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem varius, consectetur quam in, blandit leo. Integer consectetur congue nulla ac sollicitudin. Sed in erat quam. Suspendisse eget ex lectus. Nunc eleifend elit nisl, quis faucibus nisl scelerisque eu. Vestibulum venenatis lacus magna, ut finibus nunc porttitor quis. Nulla eget tellus placerat, tincidunt massa quis, mattis dolor.</span>
                </span>
            </label>

            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 1</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 2</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 3</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 4</span>
                <span class="info">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <span class="tooltip top" style="margin-left:-155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem varius, consectetur quam in, blandit leo. Integer consectetur congue nulla ac sollicitudin. Sed in erat quam. Suspendisse eget ex lectus. Nunc eleifend elit nisl, quis faucibus nisl scelerisque eu. Vestibulum venenatis lacus magna, ut finibus nunc porttitor quis. Nulla eget tellus placerat, tincidunt massa quis, mattis dolor.</span>
                </span>
            </label>

            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 1</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 2</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 3</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 4</span>
                <span class="info">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <span class="tooltip top" style="margin-left:-155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem varius, consectetur quam in, blandit leo. Integer consectetur congue nulla ac sollicitudin. Sed in erat quam. Suspendisse eget ex lectus. Nunc eleifend elit nisl, quis faucibus nisl scelerisque eu. Vestibulum venenatis lacus magna, ut finibus nunc porttitor quis. Nulla eget tellus placerat, tincidunt massa quis, mattis dolor.</span>
                </span>
            </label>

            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 1</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 2</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 3</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 4</span>
                <span class="info">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <span class="tooltip top" style="margin-left:-155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem varius, consectetur quam in, blandit leo. Integer consectetur congue nulla ac sollicitudin. Sed in erat quam. Suspendisse eget ex lectus. Nunc eleifend elit nisl, quis faucibus nisl scelerisque eu. Vestibulum venenatis lacus magna, ut finibus nunc porttitor quis. Nulla eget tellus placerat, tincidunt massa quis, mattis dolor.</span>
                </span>
            </label>

            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 1</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 2</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 3</span>
            </label>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;color:#757575;text-align:left;line-height:1.5;margin-bottom:0;">
                <span style="padding-left:30px;">child 4</span>
                <span class="info">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <span class="tooltip top" style="margin-left:-155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem varius, consectetur quam in, blandit leo. Integer consectetur congue nulla ac sollicitudin. Sed in erat quam. Suspendisse eget ex lectus. Nunc eleifend elit nisl, quis faucibus nisl scelerisque eu. Vestibulum venenatis lacus magna, ut finibus nunc porttitor quis. Nulla eget tellus placerat, tincidunt massa quis, mattis dolor.</span>
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/, https://www.google.com/search?q=break+out+of+overflow+hidden

Comment: have you tried to move the tooltip to the right? and the top to the left, without overflowing the tooltip from the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, basically you would like to have your tooltip shifted to the right side so that it doesn't hide your list lying on left side, along with the scrolling you provided there. Here is some CSS change you can make to achieve the same :

```
.tooltip {
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: #00c853;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: none;
    top: 150%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.tooltip.top:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-top: 7px solid #00c853;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 11px;
    bottom: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #00c853;
    top: -14px;
    bottom: auto;
}
```

Also, please remove the inline style given to `<span class="tooltip top">` in the HTML.

You can view the updated code in [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/a54nmj75/2/).

Comment: I ended up adding some JS because I sometimes needed it to be more on the left. Thanks!